# Privilege levels for new Stack Exchanges

Tags: feature-request, tagging, reputation

I notice that you need 4000 rep to [edit tag wikis](https://dba.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki), but DBA is relatively new; I don't think we have *anyone* yet who can do this, so we are essentially wiki-less and may be for a few more months. There was a period, for example, where there simply weren't enough of us who could vote to close off-topic or otherwise unsuitable questions. Was this a policy decision that new sites shouldn't have wikis until they reach a critical mass? Or can we tweak this a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: If the edit is suggested, there are still the moderators who can approve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the new [suggested edits and review](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) feature, [every registered user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284) should be able to suggest an edit to tag wikis.

Are you not seeing an edit link?

Comment: I don't understand what the 4000 is for then?

Comment: @Gaius, That is the full privilege - at that level you'd be able to edit a tag wiki without it going into a queue to be peer-reviewed before being accepted.

Comment: OK cool - so who can do the review, anyone or just the >4000 users?

Comment: @Gaius, it is in the links I posted. (:

Comment: Thanks Rebecca!